# TypeError: dnn_Model.setInputMean() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)

Tags: typeerror

[image]Please resolve TypeError while executing the object detection project.

I have tried to implement the object detection program but TypeError is appearing.
I hope I will get the resolution within 24Hr of the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to give only one argument.
i.e.,

```
model.setInputMean([127.5,127.5,127.5])
```